# Convert Unix timestamp to date object swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, swift5

I need to convert a **unix timestamp** into a **date object** in the swift 5 programming language.

Unix time stamp (represented as an integer)

> 1616187198

```
print(unixTimeStamp)  //Output: 1616187198
print(Date())         //Output: 2021-03-19 23:30:30 +0000
```

How can I convert the integer unix time stamp to be represented the exact same as the Date() object.

My only guess is to use DateFormatter but im not sure how to go about this with a unix timestamp

```
static let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = .current
        dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        return dateFormatter
    }()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast the unix time stamp to a Double and call `Date(timeIntervalSince1970:)`.

(Note: That converts the time stamp to a date. But how it is *represented* visibly, in the console or any other form of string output, is a completely different matter.)